# ASP.NET error insert on DB with GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to insert on my Access BD with a GridView Footer, but when I make a submit, this give me an error

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

I just have this on my asp form `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="tts.WebForm2" %>`

and  this in my GridView `<asp:GridView ID="dataGridView1" horizontalalign="Center" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="533px" BorderColor="#999966" CellSpacing="5" ShowFooter="True">
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />`

> [ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event
>   validation is enabled using  in
>   configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page. 
>   For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to
>   postback or callback events originate from the server control that
>   originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.]
>   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId,
>   String argument) +9732654
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +125
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +12
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +35    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1639

Comment: This error has nothing to do with a database insert or a GridView. Are you manipulating input controls with javascript perhaps?

Comment: @VDWWD no, i'm not using javascript or something like that. Just ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you aspx file you should put the first line as this:

```
<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```

Comment: I've this problem too, but is in spanish the question [https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/68717/40111] hope you can help me